# Error Message in console on running the app on emulator: WindowSurfaceColorBuffer

Tags: android

What does this error message mean?

> setWindowSurfaceColorBuffer: bad color buffer handle 0

My app works fine and it does not seem to be affected by this message in console output in `Eclipse`. Is there some way that this message is affecting my app in producing best results?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about this message as there is nothing related to your application issue with this message. AFAIK, you can ignore this message and move ahead without much worries...  But, Let me also see if someone can throw light on your issue and suggests something better than me

Comment: Doesn't seem to be affecting test results for me, either. I think this is simply a UI bug occurring on the latest versions of the emulator with the latest versions of OS X.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it? I have it on my haxm emu and it's quite annoying, as it switches the perspective to Run/AVD and I can't look into logs/debug etc...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this recently, it appears that it is a bug. All I did was restart my emulator and run the app again.

Comment: Perhaps just add this as a comment

Comment: If it fixes the problem or could fix the problem, it is a valid answer.  You don't have to understand the problem 100% to make a good suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation but after much search, I progressed with the project and it still worked perfectly. So, I think you should just ignore it.

Comment: That should have been a comment; not an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error.
The best way to go is to wipe data from your emulator.
This worked for me and hopefully will work for you too.