# libGDX Strange Rendering Bug

Tags: java, libgdx

I've recently started my first libGDX game, and it is all going well, everything renders fine but after about a minute nothing renders, the rendering calls are still made and the spritebatch works fine, I'm just left with a black screen, I have even changed the 'glClearColor()' to but I'm still left with a black screen. I've have no idea what this could be.

My main class:

```
    @Override
    public void create() {
        Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(Settings.screenWidth, Settings.screenHeight, Settings.fullscreen);
        Gdx.graphics.setVSync(Settings.VSync);
        Gdx.graphics.setTitle("Trench Warfare");

        batch = new SpriteBatch(1000);

        previous = System.currentTimeMillis();

        currentMap = new Map(this, 0);

        currentMap.addObject(new ColourMapObject(this, 0));
    }

    private void update() {Settings.screenHeight, Settings.fullscreen);
        Gdx.graphics.setVSync(Settings.VSync);
        batch.setColor(new Color(Settings.brightness, Settings.brightness, Settings.brightness, 1.0f));

        float delta = ((float)(System.currentTimeMillis() - previous)) / 1000.0f;
        previous = System.currentTimeMillis();

        currentMap.update(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() { //Always called
        update();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1); //Red colour still black screen.
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        currentMap.render(batch); //Basicly list of textures to be rendered, they never stop rendering (Being called) despite black screen.
        batch.end();

        batch.flush();
    }
```

EDIT:
We've determined that after some time SpriteBatch render a black screen over the red clear colour, It also stops rendering the texture.
I've also determined that the SpriteBatch's tint or colour stays white even during the black screen.

EDIT, this code takes in a texture and then turns into a different texture with different colours:

```
public class ColourMapObject extends MapObject {

    public enum Type {
        Dirt,
        Water,
        Trench,
    }

    private Texture terrainMap;
    private Texture trenchMap;
    private Texture soldierMap;
    private Texture buildingMap;
    private Texture shipMap;
    private int levelId;

    private Texture finalTexture;
    private Type[][] types;

    public ColourMapObject(TrenchMain main, int levelId) {
        super(main);
        this.levelId = levelId;

        //finalTexture = new Texture("/map" + String.valueOf(levelId) + "/terrainMap.png");
        finalTexture = new Texture("black.png");
        finalTexture.getTextureData().prepare();
        loadMap(levelId);
    }

    private void loadMap(int levelId) {
        //terrainMap = new Texture("/map" + String.valueOf(levelId) + "/terrainMap.png");
        terrainMap = new Texture("terrainMap.png");
        types = new Type[terrainMap.getWidth()][terrainMap.getHeight()];

        terrainMap.getTextureData().prepare();
        Pixmap pixmap = terrainMap.getTextureData().consumePixmap();

        for(int x = 0; x < terrainMap.getWidth(); x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < terrainMap.getHeight(); y++) {
                types[x][y] = RandomMapColour.getType(new Color(pixmap.getPixel(x, y)));
                if(types[x][y] == null) types[x][y] = Type.Dirt;
            }
        }

//      trenchMap = new Texture("/map" + String.valueOf(levelId) + "/trenchMap.png");
//      
//      
//      soldierMap = new Texture("/map" + String.valueOf(levelId) + "/soldierMap.png");
//      
//      
//      buildingMap = new Texture("/map" + String.valueOf(levelId) + "/buildingMap.png");
//      
//      
//      shipMap = new Texture("/map" + String.valueOf(levelId) + "/shipMap.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float delta) {
        super.update(delta);

        Pixmap draw = new Pixmap(Settings.screenWidth, Settings.screenHeight, Format.RGB888);

        float pX = (float)terrainMap.getWidth() / (float)draw.getWidth();
        float pY = (float)terrainMap.getHeight() / (float)draw.getHeight();

        for(int x = 0; x < draw.getWidth(); x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < draw.getHeight(); y++) {
                switch(types[(int)((float)x * pX)][(int)((float)y * pY)]) {
                case Dirt:
                    draw.drawPixel(x, y, RandomMapColour.getDirtColour());
                    break;
                case Trench:
                    draw.drawPixel(x, y, RandomMapColour.getTrenchColour());
                    break;
                case Water:
                    draw.drawPixel(x, y, RandomMapColour.getWaterColour());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        finalTexture = new Texture(draw);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        super.render(batch);
        float sx = ((float)TrenchMain.getScreenWidth()) / ((float)finalTexture.getWidth());
        float sy = ((float)TrenchMain.getScreenHeight()) / ((float)finalTexture.getHeight());

        batch.draw(finalTexture, 0, 0, 0, 0, finalTexture.getWidth(), finalTexture.getHeight(), sx, sy, 0, 0, 0, finalTexture.getWidth(), finalTexture.getHeight(), false, false);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `Gdx.graphics.setVSync` every frame? Also you can get the `delta` by calling `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime`, instead of using `System.currentTimeMillis() - pervious`.

Comment: Another thing is that `batch.end()` calls `flush()`, so you shouldn't need to call it yourself. I'd try removing that.

Comment: @Springrbua Using Gdx's delta time didn't work.

Comment: @MPeti thanks, I remove the flush but with still the same black screen.

Comment: @user2693587 I sometimes get black screens when I accidentally unload assets too early (and then use them). Is `currentMap` being disposed/unloaded?

Comment: @user2016436 No, I've checked nothing is unloaded, It still renders but the screen just stays black.

Comment: What does "using GDx's delta time didn't work mean"? Thats what almost everyone uses, when working with libgdx, so i doubt that it does not work...

Comment: @Springrbua I mean it changed nothing as excpected, please don't worry about my methods or finding delta times etc but rather finding the answer to this stange issue. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say, with only those few lines of code, but your `update()` method just seems strange to me. For example you are setting `VSync` every frame. Also we don't know what the `currentMap.update()` does. Anyways, try to remove the `batch.begin()`-`batch.end()` block, just to see, if it then clears the screen with Red-Color.

Comment: @Springrbua Haha, you're a genius. The screen stays red even after a coule of minutes longer than when the black screen kicks in. I'll investigate further.

Comment: But the black screen still kicks in, just after a longer time?

Comment: @Springrbua no, it never kicks in. I've edited the post.

Comment: So we can be sure, that there is something wrong with the `SpriteBatch`/the drawing with it. Can you show us the "currentMap.render(batch)" method? Also ensure, that you always have only 1 "Renderer" running at a time. That means you have to call `end` before calling `begin` of another "Renderer". The "Renderers" are `ShapeRenderer`, `SpriteBatch` and `ModelBatch`, not sure if i forgot some...

Comment: @Springrbua I only have one renderer (SpriteBatch) i'll post the new code above in a minute.

Comment: Are those `Texture`s changing every few frames? I ask cause you are creating a new `Texture` every frame. Also the calculation of the new `Texture` seems pretty heavy to me. This should generally be avoided if possible (remember, that update is called many times per second). And the `Texture` you are creating can't get Black after some time or could that be?

Comment: @Springrbua I understand that is intensive but I have printed the values of the colours of the pixels on the `finalTextire` and have proven there is still colour.

Comment: @Springrbua I launched it on a android simulator and I get this error:
`[2015-06-23 19:54:48 - Emulator] setWindowSurfaceColorBuffer: bad color buffer handle 0`

Comment: Does the app stil run? It seems to be a [ignorable warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288231/error-message-in-console-on-running-the-app-on-emulator-windowsurfacecolorbuffe)

Comment: @Springrbua No, it says it four times, in batches of two. the first two it runs then ~5 seconds later the second batch is printed and android says "Trench Warfare - Is not respondign"

Comment: It's hard to say whats worng here... Try to google for this error, maybe you find something. Also try to remove unneccessary code form the `update` method, i don't guess you have to set VSnyc every frame, it should only be set on change. Same thing with the `DisplayMode`. Also, if it is possible, try to reuse the `Texture`s instead of recreating them, if possible.

Comment: @Springrbua I've googled it many times over nad over with no success, I'll try the rest soon, I'm not at home, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figuired it out, for those who are wonder, what I was doing was creating a new `finalTexture` every update with disposing of the old one.

Simply dispose of the texture.
`finalTexture.dispose();`